# PyZDDE (Python Zemax DDE)

Tags: python

It's first time when I use this tool (pyzdde).
When I run simple program error has occurred!

```
#**************** Add PyZDDE to Python search path **********
import sys
PyZDDEPath = 'C:\PyZDDE'  # Assuming PyZDDE was unzipped here!

if PyZDDEPath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(PyZDDEPath)
#************************************************************

import pyzdde.zdde as pyz
#Create a PyZDDE object
link = pyz.createLink()
```

ERROR: Unable to establish a conversation with server (err=0x400a).
ZEMAX may not be running!
Could not initiate instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that PyZDDE couldn't create a link to communicate with Zemax as Zemax may not be running. So, were you running Zemax when executing the above code?

By the way, you don't need to use the above template any more to use PyZDDE. Now, there is a pyzdde [PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyZDDE). So you can just use pip to install pyzdde. The installation instructions are [here](https://github.com/indranilsinharoy/PyZDDE#install-pyzdde-from-pypi). After installing, open Zemax, and then try to run the [spiral spot example](https://github.com/indranilsinharoy/PyZDDE/wiki#example).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer! but I've already used pip for installation. Also I firstly execute Zemax (run it) and then try to run any program like spiral spot. Actually I have unlicensed Zemax. Can this error be connected with it?

Comment: That's really strange! The error code `err=0x400a` suggest that [a client's attempt to establish a conversation has failed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). AFAIK, this has nothing to do with the license. Just a curious question, have you used MATLAB/ mzdde with Zemax in your system?